# "google drive hosted web page editing is not working "

Tags: google-drive-api, onedrive

I host my web page using google drive.and i want to do some changes  so i edit the html page in side the google drive using text editor and i save that file but i refresh the web page changes are not showing.but if i use another browser example internet explorer the changes are showing then i do another change and refresh the internet explorer changes are not showing. please help me.

- I tried using one-drive also same issue in here also

====================================================

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your web browser has cached the webpage, meaning it's not going to Google Drive and is instead loading the page locally in order to save time.

In order to clear the cache, you can force refresh your browser by doing the following:

- Windows **Ctrl + F5**
- Linux **F5**
- Mac **Command + R**